Innate cards when deck is reshuffled
Suppose you have a card with the Innate keyword in the discard pile.  When the deck is reshuffled (i.e., the discard pile is reshuffled and becomes the draw pile), are all cards with Innate moved to the top of the deck (i.e., drawn first)?

Why do you think Innate cards would topdeck themselves? In any case, "A discarded Innate card will be reshuffled into your draw pile like any other cards."  - https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Innate

@Malady, A fair question.  Well, I don't know whether they topdeck or don't, that's why I'm asking.  I have no particular reason to believe it works either way.  That web page says "it works as if cards with Innate are on the top of your draw pile before your first draw".  I'm asking whether the same is true for subsequent draws after a reshuffle.  Perhaps the answer is "no", and if so, I'd consider that a solid answer.  If I had to guess, I'd guess "no", but I don't actually know, and I think it'd be better to know.

I realize this might be a simple question but in the spirit of building an archive of knowledge, I thought it might be useful to document explicitly, as I didn't find this documented explicitly anywhere obvious.  If I have misunderstood the norms of this site, I apologize.

I think as shown on the wiki the answer there answers your question. Again "A discarded Innate card will be reshuffled into your draw pile like any other cards". It explicitly answers your question. Reshuffled into your draw pile means it will be randomly placed in your draw pile (like other cards are)

@D.W. - It is a simple question, but we're questioning why you're asking it at all. Nothing about the game implies that Innate would lead to topdecking, and that it only affects the opening hand, which is functionally a totally different case from drawing after a shuffle. Unless you've seen in happen in your games? In which case I'd say it's just luck / confirmation bias, unless they keep coming up first?

Good point.  I didn't read carefully enough.  I have no reason for asking beyond curiousity.  I apologize for taking up your time for something that I could have figured out on my own.

Well, you got an answer and some points so that's good.

No.
As established in comments:
https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Innate

A discarded Innate card will be reshuffled into your draw pile like any other cards.

